# How can I share a resource between two versions of a function in tensorflow 2.4 autograph?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to share selected tensors between two versions of a function. I have made a simple example to illustrate what I'm looking for and what I have tried (the actual code is a mouthful for the moment).

I have the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
g = tf.Graph()

def function_factory(function_type):
    g.add_to_collection("shared_value", tf.Variable(200))

    @tf.function
    def set_value(value):
        g.clear_collection("shared_value")
        g.add_to_collection("shared_value", tf.Variable(value))

    @tf.function
    def get_value():
        return g.get_collection("shared_value")[0]

    @tf.function
    def get_value_with_factor(factor):
        return factor*g.get_collection("shared_value")[0]

    if function_type=="A":
        get_value.set_value = set_value
        return get_value
    elif function_type=="B":
        get_value_with_factor.set_value = set_value
        return get_value_with_factor

get_value_a = function_factory("A") 
get_value_b = function_factory("B") 

tf.print(get_value_a())
tf.print(get_value_b(10))

get_value_a.set_value(300)

tf.print(get_value_a())
tf.print(get_value_b(10))
```

and get this error:

```
ValueError: tf.function-decorated function tried to create variables on non-first call.
```

Without the @tf.function annotations (i.e. in eager mode):

```
import tensorflow as tf
g = tf.Graph()

def function_factory(function_type):
    g.add_to_collection("shared_value", tf.Variable(200))

    def set_value(value):
        g.clear_collection("shared_value")
        g.add_to_collection("shared_value", tf.Variable(value))

    def get_value():
        return g.get_collection("shared_value")[0]

    def get_value_with_factor(factor):
        return factor*g.get_collection("shared_value")[0]

    if function_type=="A":
        get_value.set_value = set_value
        return get_value
    elif function_type=="B":
        get_value_with_factor.set_value = set_value
        return get_value_with_factor


get_value_a = function_factory("A") 
get_value_b = function_factory("B") 

tf.print(get_value_a())
tf.print(get_value_b(10))

get_value_a.set_value(300)

tf.print(get_value_a())
tf.print(get_value_b(10))
```

the output is exactly what I would like it to be:

```
200
2000
300
3000
```

Any suggestions for how I could solve the error in the graph version (top) or any other suggestions for how I might share selected tensors between functions in TensorFlow autograph mode would be much appreciated. We're using TensorFlow 2.4.

Eager mode is too slow for our real problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not create new [`tf.Variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable) objects, but instead use [`assign`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable#assign) to update the value of the existing variable:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
g = tf.Graph()

def function_factory(function_type):
    g.add_to_collection("shared_value", tf.Variable(200))

    @tf.function
    def set_value(value):
        # Assign new value here instead of creating new variable
        return g.get_collection("shared_value")[0].assign(value)

    @tf.function
    def get_value():
        return g.get_collection("shared_value")[0]

    @tf.function
    def get_value_with_factor(factor):
        return factor*g.get_collection("shared_value")[0]

    if function_type=="A":
        get_value.set_value = set_value
        return get_value
    elif function_type=="B":
        get_value_with_factor.set_value = set_value
        return get_value_with_factor

get_value_a = function_factory("A") 
get_value_b = function_factory("B") 

tf.print(get_value_a())
tf.print(get_value_b(10))

get_value_a.set_value(300)

tf.print(get_value_a())
tf.print(get_value_b(10))
```

Output:

```
200
2000
300
3000
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. Works like a charm also in the real code!